# Matplotlib: How do we control figure border and axes borders padding with respect to figure and between multiple axes as well?

Tags: matplotlib

Unable to control figure border and axes borders padding with respect to figure and between multiple axes as well using fig.add_axes  or plt.subplot_adjust

```
Code:

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt8

`axs=[] 
fig=plt8.figure(figsize=(6.0,4.0),edgecolor='red',linewidth=10,dpi=100) 
print(fig)   
ax1=fig.add_axes([0.6,1,2.0,1.5])
axs+=[ax1]
ax2=fig.add_axes([3.3,1,2.0,1.5])
axs+=[ax2]`

Description:
```

This is figsize=(6.0,4.0)
As per co-ordinates given by me,
I want to have 2 rectangle plots inside the above figure

Gap between the 2 plots is 0.7 and
width=2.0 for both plots
height=1.5 for both plots
left pad with respect to figure is 0.6
right pad is 1.1
top pad is 1.5
bottom pad is 1

```
But this is not working , can anyone suggest solution code ?
```

Comment: Hi @fdireit ,(1)**my **requirement is like: top padding between 2 plots and figure is 1.5, bottom padding between figure and 2 plots is 1 (keeping in mind top pad>bottom pad) and left pad of first subplot (with figure) is 0.6 and right pad of second subplot (with figure) is 0.7 (keeping in mind right pad (right pad>left pad) and horizontal distance between 2 subplots is 0.7. width of each subplot is 2.0, height of each subplot is 1.5. So Figure size is 6*4 which is (0.6(left pad)+2(w)+0.7(gap between plots)+2(w)+0.7(right pad))*(1(bottom pad)+1.5(h)+1.5(top pad)

Answer (score 0):

The dimensions you use when calling `add_axes()` need to be fractions of the figure (see [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes)).

The tuple required is "(left, bottom, width, height)".

Therefore:

```
ax1=fig.add_axes([0.6/6.0, 1.0/4.0, 2.0/6.0, 1.5/4.0])
ax2=fig.add_axes([3.3/6.0, 1.0/4.0, 2.0/6.0, 1.5/4.0])
```

Dividing by 6.0, for left position and width, given that you specify 6.0 as figure width. Dividing by 4.0, for bottom position and height, given you specify 4.0 as your figure height.